# Round Percentages PHP

Tags: php, variables, math, echo, divide

I'm currently dividing two values in order to get the percentage from the actual count and the total count for my application.

I am using the following formula:

```
echo ($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100;
```

That is giving me a value like: 79.2312313. I would perefer a value like 79%.

I have tried the following:

```
echo round($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100;
```

this doesn't seem to work correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: add the `* 100` inside of the round: `echo round($fakecount / $totalcount * 100);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try,

```
echo (int)($fakecount * 100 / $totalcount + .5);
```

This works because adding 0.5 increases the integer part by 1 if the decimal part is `>= .5`

or,

```
round ($fakecount * 100 / $totalcount);
```

Note that, I'm doing the multiplication by 100 before the division to better preserve the precision.

Comment: Casting to `int` is the same as `floor()`. Use `round()` to get the nearest value.

Comment: @rjmunro my one will return the same value as round() as I added 0.5 before type casting :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that. Are you sure that the performace of casting to int is better than using round() by enough of a margin to be faster than the extra addition?

Comment: @rjmunro: I'm not sure about the runtime performance. but not all languages have round() function, but casting to int after adding 0.5 is a good way to do in all languages. and if it's about runtime I think the difference would be negligible as round function has to do something similar (I don't know exactly how `round()` rounds a number)

Answer (score 7):

You need to multiply by 100 before you round, not after:

```
echo round($fakecount * 100 / $totalcount);
```

You are calculating `$fakecount / $totalcount`, which will be a number between 0 and 1, then you round that, so you get either 0 or 1, then you multiply by 100, giving either 0 or 100 for your percentage.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo intval(($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100);
```

Or you can use

```
echo floor(($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100);  //Round down
```

Or

```
echo ceil(($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100);  // Round Up
```

Comment: `intval()` is the same as `floor()`. Use `round()`

Answer (score 0):

use the round() function

```
echo round(($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

others you can use are

- ceil() - Round fractions up
- floor() - Round fractions down

Answer (score 0):

Nope...

There is a lot of ways to do it.

```
$mypercent = ($fakecount / $totalcount) * 100;
```

Remember.. this will first run what is inside of (xxx) and after will * 100.

After this...

```
echo round($mypercent);
```

And you can use a lot of rules on that too if you want...

```
<i>if ($value < 10) {
    $value = floor($value);
} else {
    $value = round($value);
}</i>
```

Dont forget to see that other to commands too, maybe you are going to need it.

ceil() - Round fractions up

floor() - Round fractions down

=)